# Change JSON value with PHP script

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON http://pastebin.com/index/LwAhi59r

And I have a PHP script in which I want to change my JSON value of each domain and template from each site. I would like to know what would be a good PHP code to change the values with an input and a selector in which you can choose which site you want to change it from. I got this php code I think it a good start but I don't know how to proceed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Domain of Template veranderen met PHP script</h2>
    <form action="process.php" id="form" method="post">
          <select name="selector">
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">cms18.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">dmmd.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">opmaat.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">opmaatdebiteurenadvies.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">navbar.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">test18.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">huisartsplus.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">robertenrademaker.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">tilburg.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">cbk-groningen.test.silverbee.nl</option>
        <option value="cms18.test.silverbee.nl">getbusyinc.test.silverbee.nl</option>
    </select>
           Value:<input type="text" name="value">
          
          <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
<br>
 
<?php 
    $select = $_POST['selector'];
    //neem de json bestand array in php
    $lijst= file_get_contents('list.json');
    /*echo $lijst;*/
 
    //neem de lijst json en decodeerd het json string. als true maakt hij er een array van.
    $decoderen= json_decode($lijst, true);
    /*echo $decoderen;*/
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($decoderen as $key => $value) 
            {
                echo "<li>".$key."<ul>";
                foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) 
                {
                    echo "<li>".$key1.": ".$value1."</li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>"."</li>";
            }
    echo "</ul>";
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*foreach ($decoderen as $key => $value) {
    if((string)$key-> == $this->put('')) {
        $value->name="--";(string)$value->description="--";
    }*/ This is the last code i was trying to use i found this in another site someone had same problem but i couldnt come out with this. BTW i am new in PHP.
        
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help by posting your code here. Also "what would be a good solution" sounds like asking an opinion. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah what i want to do is to change Json with an input. so that people can do it faster. so if you select like one of the sites than choose wich you want to change Domain or template and than when you put the value if will change. but i got no idea how to start. i made this but i think its going bad thats the reason i came here

Comment: Ok, so you want to take a json list, convert it to values a human can read, allow them to edit the value, and then convert back to json for storage?

Comment: Exactly man that is it

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    $list = file_get_contents('list.json');
    $list = json_decode($list, true);

    $selector = $_POST['selector'];

    if (isset($selector))
    {
        // overwrite the selected domain of the list with the new value if they are not empty
        if (isset($_POST['domain']))
        {
            $list[$selector]['domain'] = $_POST['domain'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['template']))
        {               
            $list[$selector]['template'] = $_POST['template'];
        }

        // store the new json
        file_put_contents('list.json', json_encode($list));
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Domain of Template veranderen met PHP script</h2>
        <form action="process.php" id="form" method="post">
            <select name="selector">
            <?php foreach ($list AS $key => $value) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value['domain']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="domain" placeholder="Domain">
            <input type="text" name="template" placeholder="Template">

            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx i will try it i been away for 2 days weekend i will try it today thx you!!

Comment: I tryed what you sad but now i see that its the domain and template that will be changed and not the values inside them, what i want to that i can select the url and change the values inside domain or template and that you also can choose domain or template and than change the values inside. i got this now http://pastebin.com/DB5VbF2i  i couldnt paste it here it was too big

Comment: now i get template like 11x i only want to choose url and template or domain that i can choose between both and than the new value in side the one i choose